# Jest toBeCloseTo's precision not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to use `toBeCloseTo` in Jest to test a floating point number:

```
expect(value).toBeCloseTo(0.01491, 5);
```

But when I run my test, I see this result:

```
Precision: 5-digit
Expected: 0.01491
Received: 0.01491570355
```

When I set the precision to `4`, the test passes, but I'm confused. In the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tobeclosetonumber-numdigits), it says:

> Use `numDigits` to control how many digits after the decimal point to check

So, I'm assuming here that I'm comparing the correct number of digits: I have `.01491`, which has `5` digits, so I expect (pun intended!) the test to compare exactly those digits and pass.

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [actual comparison code used by Jest's `toBeCloseTo` method](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/main/packages/expect/src/matchers.ts#L184) is as follows:

```js
      expectedDiff = Math.pow(10, -precision) / 2;
      receivedDiff = Math.abs(expected - received);
      pass = receivedDiff < expectedDiff;
```

(Oddly enough the documentation lists the second parameter `precision` as `numDigits` instead.)

Your test fails because the difference between the expected value and the actual value exceeds 0.5 × 10<sup>−5</sup>: it's about 0.57 × 10<sup>−5</sup>.  Rounded to five decimal places, the received value `0.01491570355` is `0.01492`.

As far as I can see the logic behind a comparison such as this is that the actual value will be considered close to the expected value to within `numDigits` digits if the expected value is what you get from rounding the actual value to `numDigits` decimal places.

Comment: Thank you @Luke, the tip to think of it as `what you get from rounding the value` was VERY helpful

Comment: so think of it as ceil / floor (round) value instead of substring?

Comment: @Dheeraj, yes.  Suppose the expected value is `0.01491` and the actual value is `0.01490999977974`.  That actual value would fail a substring check despite differing from the expected value by about 2.2 × 10^(-10).

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for a way to have more expected api, you can override it like this:

```
expect.extend({
  toBeCloseTo(received: number, expected: number, precision: number) {
    const pass = Math.abs(received - expected) < precision;
    return {
      pass,
      message: () =>
        `expected ${received} to be close to ${expected} with precision ${precision}`,
    };
  },
});
```

Then the use case becomes:

```
  expect(bullet.x).toBeCloseTo(886, 1); // meaning maximum 1 higher or 1 lower
```